# Excel VBA - Unhiding rows clears their formatting

Tags: excel, vba

When I call the following, it will clear any conditional formatting that was previously applied to those cells:

```
Sub UnhideAll()
    Columns.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why. Using Excel 2016. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: What is the conditional formatting rule? This does not clear formatting for me so I would check to see what range your rule is applied to

Comment: ... or if your rule is dependant on visible/hidden rows? Maybe the `Aggregate` function?

Comment: There are several columns (D to AQ) that get updated once a week. The formatting changes the cell color to green, if its lower then the previous week, and red if its higher (it stays white if no change). Its a pretty simple format rule. I didn't make the original formatting rules, the doc was given to me, and it was working fine. Now I'm being asked to hide any row with all 0s. Frankly, I'm too lazy to do and undo this each week. As Ross suggest, now that I look at the formatting, it might actually be easier to do the formatting in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps not the best fix but could you program the conditional formatting into the VBA code. When you unhide the columns could the conditional formatting be reapplied?

Comment: Looking at how the person who did the formatting rules, this idea may actually be more elegant.